# Remove_if predicate for list

Tags: c++

why won't this work when i use template function predicate.

```
class A
{
    int x;
public:
    A(int X):x(X){}
    int getX() const {return x;}
};

template <typename T>
bool less_than_two(T const &a)
{
    return (a.getX()<2);
}

int main()
{
    list <A> l;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        l.push_back(i);

    l.remove_if(less_than_two);
}
```

Comment: `less_than_two` is a function template, not a function. Instantiate it to get a function, like Naveen says.

Comment: Note that this gets easier when you use a function object `struct less_than_two { template<typename T> bool operator()(const T& a) {return a.getX()<2;} };` This also has the advantage that compilers are more likely to `inline` calls to member functions of function objects (`operator()()` is a member function) than calls through function pointers.

Answer (score 5):

You need to instantiate the template with type `A`. So you need to do `l.remove_if(less_than_two<A>);`